# Bukkit Plugin Exploding Arrow

Tags: bukkit

I have a bukkit plugin but i want my arrows to explode. I have this piece of code:

```
 public void ArrowHit(ProjectileHitEvent e)
      {
        if (((e.getEntity() instanceof Arrow)) && 
          ((e.getEntity().getShooter() instanceof Player)))
        {
          Player shooter = (Player)e.getEntity().getShooter();

            double x = e.getEntity().getLocation().getX();
            double y = e.getEntity().getLocation().getY();
            double z = e.getEntity().getLocation().getZ();
            e.getEntity().getWorld().createExplosion(x, y, z, 2.0F, false,   false);

        }
```

at the bottom of my main class. And it doesnt work. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: What does it do instead of working?

Comment: @zwol Not work? It just shoots the arrow and doesn't explode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204943/spigot-bukkit-help-block-manipulation

Answer (score 2):

First, you should make sure you have registered your listener in the `onEnable()` method! Example:

```
public void onEnable() {
    this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
}
```

Once this is done, check if you have the [`@EventHandler` annotation](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Event_API_Reference#.40EventHandler) before your event.

You can also add a priority! Example:

```
@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGH)
public void ArrowHit(ProjectileHitEvent e) {
    if (e.getEntity() instanceof Arrow && e.getEntity().getShooter() instanceof Player) {
        Player shooter = (Player) e.getEntity().getShooter();

        double x = e.getEntity().getLocation().getX();
        double y = e.getEntity().getLocation().getY();
        double z = e.getEntity().getLocation().getZ();
        e.getEntity().getWorld().createExplosion(x, y, z, 2.0F, false,   false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first is to check to make sure you registered the listener and you have given the method the EventHandler annotation. If that doesn't work, put some sysouts/souts around the code to see where things go awry. As far as I can tell, everything codewise is fine from the block you posted besides the chance of the missing annotation.

```
public class Example implements Listener {

    public Example(JavaPlugin plugin) {
        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onGUIClick(InventoryClickEvent e) {
        // foo
    }
}
```

Different event, but same premise.