# Spigot/Bukkit Help : Block Manipulation

Tags: java, bukkit

I don't know why this isn't working.
I tried execute it, but when I type `/build`, the redstone block doesn't place.

### plugin.yml

```
name: SkinStandoff
version: 0.1
main: com.sumeshdesh.skinstandoff.SkinStandoff
commands:
   arena:
    usage: /build
```

### Main.java

```
public class SkinStandoff extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

public boolean onCommand(Command cmd, CommandSender sender, String label, String args[]) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("build") && sender instanceof Player) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        Location start;
        Block bEnd;
        Location end;

        start = player.getLocation();
        end = start.add(3, -1, 3);
        bEnd = end.getBlock();
        getLogger().info(bEnd.toString());
        bEnd.setType(Material.REDSTONE_BLOCK);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: There was no errors, and everything worked smoothly except the command..

Comment: You're going to have to give us more details if you want a good answer. For starters, have you set up your plugin.yml correctly? (show us the setup)

Comment: @Xetnus Thank You.

Comment: @Sumesh No problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**plugin.yml**

Without knowing anything more about your setup, I can tell you that your `plugin.yml` was set up incorrectly. Specifically, the `commands` section. Your `plugin.yml` should probably look something like this:

```
name: SkinStandoff
version: 0.1
main: com.sumeshdesh.skinstandoff.SkinStandoff
commands:
    build:
        usage: Type /build to place the block!
```

Before, where the line `build:` is now, you had `arena:`. This meant that player would have to type `/arena`, instead of `/build`. And, unless I'm incorrect, I think you expect the player to type `/build`. You can read more about setting up your `plugin.yml` by [checking out the Plugin YAML wiki.](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_YAML)

**onCommand**

The first two parameters of your `onCommand` method should be switched. This:

```
onCommand(Command cmd, CommandSender sender, String label, String args[])
```

should be replaced with:

```
onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args)
```

Also, there's no reason for you to check if the command `/build` was entered. Unless you've registered more than one command in your `plugin.yml`, you can be certain that the player entered `/build`, otherwise your `onCommand` method wouldn't have been called. So, my suggestion is to replace this line:

```
if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("build") && sender instanceof Player) {
```

with this line:

```
if (sender instanceof Player) {
```

You can read more about the `onCommand` method and about Bukkit plugins in general by [checking out the Plugin Tutorial wiki.](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Plugin_Tutorial#The_onCommand.28.29_Method)